# Is there a control chart option in BIRT (eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, charts, controls, birt

I am using BIRT to try and mimic the style of a sample report that uses control charts; is such a feature available in BIRT? I don't see it in the list of available chart options, but figured I would ask in case I am missing something.

Comment: visit this link TCR does not come bundled with BIRT but is available for download http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v61r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itm.doc_6.3%2Fadminuse%2Ftcr_prereqs.htm

Comment: I assume the poster means statistical process control charts.

Comment: Following your link (from Germany), I don't see control charts mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know.

For our product we developed a Java Bean for displaying statistical process control charts using JFreeChart.

Recently, we decided to adopt this solution for BIRT: We added an SVG export API to the bean.
Then, we access the bean with BIRT and tell it to export the chart(s) as SVG file(s).
BIRT renders the SVG file(s) as image(s) and finally deletes the file(s).
That way, our BIRT PDF report contains the charts as vector graphics, with excellent print quality and small file size.

However, it was very tricky to develop this.